# Creating new database connection in a class to use

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to create a class that can handle all of my personal needs about a MySQL database.

I want to create a method in that class that will open the connection to the database and one that will close the open connection.

So I thought I can just create a connection outside of the methods and work with it in the methods, but I don't know if or how I can do that.

```
class Sql
{
    public string cs { get; set; }
 
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(cs);

    public void Open()
    {
        connection.Open();
    }
    public void Close()
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try for example [SQLite-Net Code-First ORM](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) with [BindingListView](https://github.com/waynebloss/BindingListView) for bindings and filters.

Answer (score 1):

Like the comments say, a much better pattern is to create and open the connection only when you need it, and dispose it as soon as you are done.

```
using (var con = new MySqlConnection(cs))
{
    con.Open();
    // do a a single DB operation with con
}
```

Creating a connection is not expensive because most underlying providers use connection pooling.

Answer (score -1):

your connection string should look something like this, depending on where the database is located:

```
string cs = "server=localhost;database=testDB;"
```

Note that the server can be something like SQLEXPRESS or your local db, and the name will obviously change depending on what you name it. Check out online tutorials on how to set up a db and get the connection string for it.